# Overriding Basic iOS Gestures

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipad

I was wondering if there is a way to override basic gestures included in the OS, such as dragging down from the status bar to view the lock screen, or swiping diagonally from the top right. This way I could prevent a user from accessing this information while the app is in a public-facing lobby setting.

Comment: Yes, look at / for something called "kiosk mode".

Comment: @luk2302 That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a bunch!